# How to transfer money from user to merchant/admin account using Dwolla ACH api?

Tags: php, api, payment, dwolla

I am creating a script for tansfer money from one bank account to another bank using dwolla ACH API. My code is working fine when i am trying to transfer money from admin funding source to user account but i am getting issue when i send money user to admin. Have a look on below code:-

```
$transfersApi = new DwollaSwagger\TransfersApi($apiClient);

$new_xfer = $transfersApi->create(array (
  '_links' => 
    array (
      'destination' => 
      array (
        'href' => 'https://api.dwolla.com/customers/789a5d4c-2b0e-4c1c-80cf-5b3ccfccc0e3',
      ),
      'source' => 
      array (

        'href' => 'https://api.dwolla.com/funding-sources/a7afee62-e058-4c69-b417-d0187a3a053f',
      ),
    ),
  'amount' => 
    array (
      'currency' => 'USD',
      'value' => '5.50',
    ),
    'metadata' => 
    array (
      'foo' => 'bar',
      'baz' => 'boo',
    ),
));
```

error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DwollaSwagger\ApiException' with message '[400] Error connecting to the API (api-uat.dwolla.com/transfers)'; in /var/www/html/dwolla/dwolla-swagger-php-master/dwolla-swagger-php-master/vendor/‌​dwolla/dwollaswagger/lib/ApiClient.php:308 Stack trace: –
```

Please help me

Comment: What error are you seeing ?

Comment: This API always throw exception: Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'DwollaSwagger\ApiException' with message '[400] Error connecting to the API (https://api-uat.dwolla.com/transfers)' in /var/www/html/dwolla/dwolla-swagger-php-master/dwolla-swagger-php-master/vendor/dwolla/dwollaswagger/lib/ApiClient.php:308
Stack trace:

Comment: @ScottStensland, I am using 3 step for fund transfer. 1. Create user, 2.) Add funding sourece 3.) Transfer money.

Comment: Please put output including errors into a Code Block in your Question so its human readable